# Angular: ng-src have jquery as initiator in chrome network devtool?

Tags: angularjs

I was trying to understand underpar performances from s3 image hosting when I notice something strange.

I have some picture using `ng-src` to build a dynamic url, when I look in the network pane it says the initator is jquery, removing the jquery dependency makes it be angular. I was wondering what that meant.

Bonus question: is it normal that under 100kb takes up to 5s to load from s3?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular uses jQuery if jQuery is present, otherwise it uses it's own jqLight implementation: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element